# Изменить значение в Json js

Tags: javascript, json

```
goods = 3:{id: "3", title: "Название товара", price: "7300", count: 1, countMax: "15"}

goods[data.id]["count"] = parseInt(goods[data.id]["count"]) + 1;
```

В `data` приходит объект абсолютно такой же. И нужно просто увеличить значение `count`.

Так как на примере делаю, объект остается неизменным. Как увеличить значение `count`?

Comment: Какой-то у вас не валидный `JSON`.

Comment: В консоли нет ошибок.

Comment: Это хорошо, что нет ошибок. Только все равно, `JSON` который вы привели в примере - не валидный. А именно `goods = 3:{id: "3", title: "Название товара", price: "7300", count: 1, countMax: "15"}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не хватало фигурных скобок в объекте *goods*. Теперь всё меняется:

```js
var data = {id: 3},
goods =
{
 3:
 {
  id: "3",
  title: "Название товара",
  price: "7300",
  count: 1,
  countMax: "15"
 }
};

console.log(goods[data.id]["count"]); //1
goods[data.id]["count"] = goods[data.id]["count"] + 1;
console.log(goods[data.id]["count"]); //2

//Вывод всего объекта *goods* целиком:
console.log(goods);  //count = 2
```

Comment: Фигурные скобки есть в объекте, просто я скинул копию из консоли. Вы выведите в консоль сам объект goods целиком. Уверен будет все на месте.

Comment: @Владимир, что-то не понятно мне устраивает ли вас моё решение или нет? У меня всё работает. Нажмите внизу моего кода на кнопку "Выполнить" и посмотрите что у вас выдаёт.

Comment: Видимо я что-то не то делаю, у меня не работает, у Вас работает. Значит буду сам разбираться. Спасибо.